# HTTP Failure, clear text not permitted en Android 9

Tags: android, ionic, https

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una app que estoy desarrollando en ionic y cuando la compilo en un dispositivo android version 8.1 me funciona sin problema, esta app se conecta a una base de datos, pero al hacer la misma pruebas en un dispositivo con version de android 9 no me conecta al servidor me sale el siguiente error.
[image: Error]

Ambos estan en modo desarrollador, alguien ha pasado por lo mismo, algun consejo. Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Despues de buscar, encontre que desde Android version 9 no acepta peticiones http solo https. segui los pasos de este link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted
En el archivo config.xml agrege esta linea dentro del tag platform android

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merg target="/manifest/application">
       <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
            </edit-config>
```

ademas agrege esta linea en el tag widget

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Espero que sea util para otros. Saludos

Comment: Es importante notar que `usesCleartextTraffic` solo debe ser usado durante el proceso de desarrollo, y no para ambientes de produccion.

Comment: Por que solo se debe usar para desarrollo?

Comment: @LuisHernandez puede ser usado en producción, poco a poco se obliga que todo el ecosistema use por seguridad urls https:// cifradas, pero puede usarse sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación:

> A partir de Android 9 (API nivel 28), la compatibilidad "ClearText"
> está deshabilitada de forma predeterminada.

Ya que esta deshabilitada (`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="false" />` ), debes habilitarla para poder realiza peticiones a urls no cifradas `http://`.

Asegura de tener lo siguiente en tu archivo `config.xml` de tu proyecto Ionic:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
```

Esta opción puede ser usada en producción mientras aseguras que todas las url que uses cambien a `https://` en las futuras versiones de tu aplicación.

Revisar:

[mi aplicación android 9 no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet)