# mi aplicación android 9 no se conecta a internet: "Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted"

Tags: android, android-studio, https, security

Tengo el soporte de actualizar una aplicación en android 8 a android 9. he revisado los manuales para migrar y los cambios. mi mainactivity se abre sin problemas en la  simulación, pero debuggeando me di cuenta que la aplicación no se conecta a internet, a pesar que las librerias estan correctas y la verificación esta bien en sintaxis.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

mainactivity:

```
boolean sino = isOnlineNet();
        if(sino)
        {

        }else{
            //butacept.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            String dati="Es necesario contar con una conexión de internet activa...";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dati, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

esta es la parte para verificar la conexion, y regresa False y por lo tanto no hay conexion.

```
public Boolean isOnlineNet () {

        try {
            Process p;
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 201.162.182.189");

            int val = p.waitFor();
            boolean reachable = (val == 0);
            return reachable;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: Pero, ¿de dónde sacaste ese código para determinar la conexión? [Android explica cómo comprobar la conexión a internet](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring?hl=es-419), hazlo como ellos indican. Es cierto que a veces puede haber conexión pero que transmisión de datos. [Al final de esta respuesta hay una forma simple de verificar eso también](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570292/5587982).

Comment: Echale un vistazo a los compañeros americanos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android :D

Comment: El problema es la compatibilidad "ClearText", seguramente estas usando urls con http://, revisa mi respuesta @fearteck , de hecho es importante revisar el LogCat , ahí se mostrará información de lo que ocurre, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como comento en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3314/95), lo ideal para detectar conexión a internet es usando los métodos del SDK, en este caso puedes ver este método de ejemplo:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

esto lo puedes ver también en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring?hl=es-419)

Para permitir la conexión a internet en tu aplicación solo es necesario el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

**Habilitar la compatibilidad "ClearText" usando `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`**

Si lo anterior lo tienes configurado correctamente y mencionas que tienes problemas en Android 9 (probablemente los siguientes sistemas operativos también), esto se debe a que probablemente estas usando urls no cifradas `http://`, debes usar urls `https://` ya que:

> A partir de Android 9 (API nivel 28), la compatibilidad "ClearText" está deshabilitada de forma predeterminada.

**ClearText**: Las aplicaciones que intenten conectarse a destinos usando solo conexiones seguras pueden desactivar la compatibilidad con Cleartext (usando el protocolo HTTP sin encriptar en lugar del protocolo HTTPS) para esos destinos. Esta opción ayuda a prevenir las regresiones accidentales en apps debido a cambios en direcciones URL generados por fuentes externas como servidores backend

Tienes dos opciones:

**• Usar urls cifradas, es decir que usan `https://`**

**• Habilitar la compatibilidad "ClearText"  para que te permita conexiones usando  `http://`, esto se realiza dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`**:**

```
   <application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```