# Android .apk: Se ha producido un error al analizar el paquete

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un pequeño programa hecho en Android con un WebView que enlaza a una URL que es http y no https.
 Al probar el programa en el emulador de Android Studio funciona bien pero cuando genero un .apk de prueba y lo instalo en el móvil al intentar abrir la aplicación me sale el siguiente mensaje: Se ha producido un error al analizar el paquete.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿ Es posible que el error sea que el WebView enlaza a una URL http en vez de a una https ? Si es así,¿ como puedo ejecutar el código de prueba con un enlace http ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

"Se ha producido un problema al analizar el paquete"

**no esta relacionado al uso de urls no cifradas en tu aplicación**, pero si estas usando este tipo de urls es importante que permitas su uso para que tu aplicación funcione, habilitando CleartextTraffic dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

Revisa:

[mi aplicación android 9 no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%c3%b3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290)

**Las causas que provocan el no poder instalar la aplicación con el error  "Se ha producido un problema al analizar el paquete" son**:

- Tratas de realizar la instalación en un dispositivo que no esta considerado en las APIs configuradas en el `build.gradle` de la aplicación.

Por ejemplo si tu dispositivo tiene Android 7 (API 24) pero tu aplicación indica como mínimo (`minSdkVersion` ) Android 8 (API 25) :

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {

       minSdkVersion 25
       targetSdkVersion 28
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

- El `versionCode` de la aplicación que tratas de instalar es menor a la que se encuentra instalada.
- Tu Dispositivo tiene varias cuentas configuradas y estas en otra sesión la cual no instalo la aplicación. Para este punto debes buscar la aplicación en Apps dentro de la configuración de tu dispositivo y eliminarla "para todos los usuarios" (Uninstall for all users).

Comment: Pues al final parece que el error era no haber puesto esto en el manifest:  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" para que me dejara navegar por una URL Http sin certificado