# Desde WebView abrir nueva ventana con una URL

Tags: javascript, android, webview-android

Tengo una URL que visualizo tanto con navegador de PC como en Android mediante WebView.

En esta URL hay unos enlaces donde hago click para mostrar otra URL abriendo una nueva ventana mediante JavaScript con:

```
Window.Open()
```

El problema es que dentro de WebView no me abre una nueva ventana o el navegador con esa URL.

NOTA IMPORTANTE: Si la URL al final enlaza a un .pdf  o a un archivo me debería indicar para descargarlo o abrirlo con alguna otra aplicación. Por ejemplo en el caso de pdf. normalmente un navegador lo descarga y luego pregunta si quiere abrirlo con una aplicación.

¿ Hay alguna manera de solucionarlo ?

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes realizar configurando un `WebViewClient` a tu `WebView`, para esto primeramente crea una clase que extienda de `WebViewClient` y dentro del mètodo `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` puedes detectar y abrir la url que desees:

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

     if (url.startsWith("https://"))) {
      view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));      
      return false;
     } else {
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
     }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

al tener esta clase configurala a tu `WebView`, ejemplo:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

Comment: Santo dios 83k :0

Comment: @Jorgesys  He intentado meter la clase como clase anónima con    visorWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  // Codigo } ); pero en la parte v.load(url); no me reconoce el objeto v y tampoco el objeto progressBar

Comment: Perdon es view.loadUrl(url); ya lo cambie en la respuesta

Comment: Lo he probado y no funciona, no se abre nada.

Comment: @Jorgesys puede ser que no funcione porque la pagina que abre es un http y no un https ? o quizás el WebView este bloqueando que se abra una ventana nueva ? Como hacen algunos navegadores como si fuera un PopUp de publicidad ?

Comment: aporta mas informaciòn, el codigo que agrego revisa si la url es https:// que es lo ideal actualmente: if (url.startsWith("https://"))) { , si vas a usar urls http:// habilita cleartexttraffic en tu aplicacion: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%c3%b3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290

Comment: @Jorgesys he revisado el manifest y si tengo puesto el cleartexttraffic. La url a la que voy termina en un .pdf me debería visualizar con el navegador el pdf. ¿ No es asi ?

Comment: Te sugiero revises el  LogCat y comentes que error tienes, todos estos detalles que ahora comentas son importantes al agregarlos inicialmente a la pregunta. agrega que error obtienes

Comment: @Jorgesys En el LogCat no sale nada en esa parte de código. Parece que me funciona algo si uso SetWebChromeClient pero no me desacarga el pdf sino que me abre el PDF directamente con Google Drive en vez de darme la opción de descargar o abrir con Drive o Navegador. Pongo el código a ver si hay alguna manera que al menos me pida descargar o abrir  con otra aplicación.

Comment: @Jorgesys debuggando parece que la parte de código que pusistes de WebViewClient funciona pero solo si el link no lo genero dinámicamente. Es decir el servidor .ASP en mi caso cuando pulso el link devuelve una URL creada dinámicamente que acaba en .pdf  el shouldOverrideUrlLoading no funciona. ¿ Como podría solucionarlo ?

Comment: @Jorgesys añado a lo que dije anteriormente creo que solo funciona si la URL esta en código HTML con <a href="miurl.pdf"></a> pero si esta como JavaScript en mi caso Windows.open("miurl.pdf") no funciona.

Comment: si, esto se abre únicamente si detecta la carga de un recurso desd eun anchor <a href="https://miurl.pdf"> , Windows.open("miurl.pdf")  no debería usarse

Answer (score 0):

Con este código consigo que me muestre un PDF cuando uso JavaScript con Window.Open() pero porque me lo abre con Google Drive. No me sale la opción donde me pregunta si Descargar o Abrir con otra aplicación. Me interesaría que me preguntara ya que puede ser que no tenga Google Drive instalado en el móvil.
Lo ideal seria que me diera el mensaje de descargar para luego si quisiera abrirlo yo con la aplicación que quisiera.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
        }
    }

 miVisorWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.visorWeb);
    miVisorWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient () );


 miVisorWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            WebView newWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            WebSettings webSettings = newWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            // Other configuration comes here, such as setting the WebViewClient

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(newWebView);
            dialog.show();

            newWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            ((WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.obj).setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        }

    });
```