# ¿Como obtener en Android un JsonArray si la matriz no tiene nombre?

Tags: android, json, http

Soy nuevo en **Android** y estoy en etapa de aprendizaje. Lo que quiero hacer es obtener un *JsonArray* de una URL pero el problema es que la matriz no tiene ningún nombre. Aclaro esto porque estuve viendo tutoriales en donde solo se explica cuando la matriz tiene un nombre específico. El codigo que tengo es el siguiente: (Estoy usando la librería *Volley*)

```
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "localhost:8080/miEndPoint", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                        JSONObject mJsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        //String name = mJsonObject.getString("nombre");
                       // Toast.makeText(Conf.this, "genero: "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Ya probe con asignarle un valor vacío al nombre de la matriz pero sigo teniendo errores, y no se de que otra forma se puede solucionar. El Json que quiero obtener es algo similar a esto:

```
[
{
id: 1,
nombre: "FEMENINO"
},
{
id: 2,
nombre: "MASCULINO"
}
]
```

Cualquier respuesta se agradece.

Comment: El problema es que tu codigo espera un JSONObject cuando lo que tienes es un JSON Array, prueba usando JsonArrayRequest

Comment: Hola, ahi edite la publicación para que veas los cambios pero sigo teniendo problemas. Sabes por que puede ser? Gracias.

Comment: Hola, prueba imprimir en el logcat lo que obtienes en el response:

Comment: Quiza esta cayendo en onErrorResponse(VolleyError error), prueba con Log.e("Request",error.toString())

Comment: Ahora el error que me esta tirando es este:
_E/Request: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted._
Tendrá que ver que quiero obtener el json de un servidor local?

Comment: @Lucas agrega este valor en tu manifestación android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Primero habilita dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml el uso de ClearText mediante : android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" y prueba nuevamente, agrega que otro problema detectas en el LogCat @Lucas

Comment: Hola, gracias por las recomendaciones. Hice lo que me dijeron y puedo obtener el json desde una URL externa pero no puedo obtenerlo desde un servidor local. Nose si tendra que ver con el problema pero en el logcat me muestra lo siguiente: _Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup36: Permission denied_  **y** _c1a11f2 Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!_

Answer (score -1):

Revisa la respuesta y dependiendo de eso recuerda que la respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.
>
> Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.

Por lo tanto de acuerdo a tu respuesta

```
[
{
id: 1,
nombre: "FEMENINO"
},
{
id: 2,
nombre: "MASCULINO"
}
]
```

es un `JSONArray` lo que debes usar:

---

De acuerdo a el error

> IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted.

Es provocado porque estas usando una url http:// , recuerda que a partir de Android 9 (API nivel 28), la compatibilidad "ClearText" está deshabilitada de forma predeterminada y debes habilitarla para soportar http:// , en tu AndroidManifest.xml agrega

```
<application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Revisa:

[mi aplicación android 9 no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290)

Corrige este problema el cual puede ser la razòn por la cual no puedas obtener los datos.