# Error en el SDK de Android Studio me da error 503 de hostinger

Tags: php, android-studio, hosting, volley, sdk

Hola comapañero quiero que ayuden con este caso y es que no encuentro como: yo hago mi petición por la url en el explorador y me trae bien desde mi cuenta gratis ver imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego hago el mismo proceso con mi host pago
[image: Hostinger pago]

lo que hice anteriormente es para corroborar que si funciona ya que son el mismo php claro esta cambiando las contraseñas y los usuarios de cada hostinger y ver que los procedimientos funcionan
Pero cuando pruebo por con mi SDK me envia este error y hostiger me ha dado muchas pero como esto es remoto las respuestan han pasado como por 8 personas y cada una me toca repetir la misma historia y se demoran en responder espero que alguien le haya pasado para que me ayude y asi adelantar con hostinger el error. Gracias  este es el error en sdk
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi PHP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema 503 es un problema generado en el servidor, es importante que primero asegures el buen funcionamiento de la pagina web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien asegurar que tu aplicacion permita conexiones http://, esto se realiza dentro de tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml, habilitando la compatibilidad "ClearText":

```
  <application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Revisa esta informacion:

[mi aplicación android 9 no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%c3%b3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290)

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias la solución es que hostiger tenia que darme un dominio porque ahí se encontraba en hariza.hostingerapp.com es un subdominio, y tocaba utilizar un dominio propio sin cloudflare. Espero que le sirva a alguien en un futuro. Gracias amigo por todo.