# Problemas con Volley en Android 4.x

Tags: android, volley

Amigos tengo el siguiente problema, este request funciona con Android 5.x en adelante pero no con Android 4.x y antes funcionaba sin problemas, dejó de funcionar de la nada.

```
    private void wsTestDeConexion() {
        tvInfo.setText(probando);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(POST, URL_TEST_DE_CONEXION, jsonStr -> {
            d(TAG_TEST, jsonStr);
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                tvInfo.setText(jo.getString(getString(p_mensaje)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> {
            d(TAG_TEST, new VolleyErrorHelper(error).toString());
            tvInfo.setText(new VolleyErrorHelper(error).toString());
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(getString(p_ws_usuario), WS_USUARIO);
                params.put(getString(p_ws_contrasena), WS_CONTRASENA);
                params.put(getString(p_paquete), getString(paquete));
                return params;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(VOLLEY_TIME, DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue queue;
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), CACHE);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        queue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        queue.start();
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Uso la dependencia: **com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1**

Siempre me genera un error NetworkError pero sólo en Android 4.x en superiores trabaja sin problemas y dejó de funcionar en aplicaciones que tienen tiempo en uso.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y agrega la traza completa del error que encuentras en el Logcat.

Comment: Detecté que si la url usa SSL me da error. Esta es la url, https://comsolje-apps.net/ws/testDeConexion si la consulto así me indica que no hay conexión, sí la envío así si me da conexión: http://comsolje-apps.net/ws/testDeConexion. Es decir, sin SSL (HTTPS)

Comment: Ok, pero no creo que eso tenga que ver con Volley, sino que `comsolje-apps.net` directamente. En todo caso, puedes revisar el error que daría Volley en ese caso para saber con más certeza qué está ocurriendo cuando falla.

Answer (score 0):

es importante saber que si estas usando urls con cifradas y no cifradas (http) actives el modo cleartext para tu aplicación dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Revisa esta respuesta

[mi aplicación android no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290)