# com.android.volley.volleyerror java.lang.runtimeexception bad url data1 (Me tira ese error al momento de verificar el usuario)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

```
package com.example.finalplataforma;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mail, contraseña;

    Button ingresar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);
        contraseña = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        ingresar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


        ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validarUSuario("http://192.168.1.9/developeru/validar_usuario.php");
            }
        });

    }

    private void validarUSuario(String Url){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (!response.isEmpty()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Principal.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "El usuario no existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map <String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("usuario", mail.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("password", contraseña.getText().toString());
                return parametros;

            }
        };


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Me dice ese error, soy nuevo en este tema y aun no logro conseguir crear un formulario de login y register, si estoy haciendo algo mal, o tienen algun video donde expliquen bien como hacer login y register o si me pueden ayudar a solucionar este problema seria de gran ayuda, si me equivoco o no especifique la pregunta, dejenme saber y lo reparare, tambien aclaro que investigue en Github y en stackoverflow en ingles y no encontre nada, tambien adjunto el video donde me estoy guiando, pero en el video no pasa este error, ademas el video es del año pasado, entonces no creo que sea por lo viejo, y si alguien que es bueno en temas de android y me quiere ayudar mas en privado le agradeceria y aqui les dejo mi DISCORD Radelpam#2169, ya que no proporcionare ni mi ip ni numero de contacto privado en un foto publico, gracias por su atencion

**Buena noche a todos**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a tu URL, asegúrate que este disponible, y además debes tratar de usar `https://` y no `http://` , si no tienes otra opción habilita la compatibilidad "ClearText" para que te permita conexiones usando http://, esto se realiza dentro de tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Revisa:

[mi aplicación android 9 no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet)