# Error 404 en android studio con la api de paypal, al querer iniciar sesión

Tags: android-studio, paypal, error404

Al querer iniciar sesión me arroja el siguiente error, estoy probando con el entorno en sandbox.
[image: Este es el error que me da al querer iniciar sesion.]

Este es mi código, cabe mencionar que estoy trabando con el sdk version 16 de paypal, tambien en el manifest tengo los permisos para que se conecte a internet. No pude rastrear el motivo de esto, ¿alguna sugerencia?.

Tengo las configuraciones iniciales.

```
ImageView imgCover;
TextView txtPrecio;
Button btnProcesar;
private static final String paypalClientID = "Ae5_kK24zOsD8v6Fm2YdjzUyGdv_9G5q47kddVX-BGmQ_Nt4aNP0ep2XqZXaXSDDagjFE5mHfIzw38zM";
private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 1717;
String token = "access_token$sandbox$dbt5qhhscd2qfcbk$ea2e9ad665bae9447796c2da5c896abf";

//Para el client id  y entorno sansbox
private static PayPalConfiguration configuration = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        .clientId(paypalClientID);

PayPalPayment thingsToBuy;
```

Despues esta el onCreate

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgCover = findViewById(R.id.imgCover);
    txtPrecio = findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);
    btnProcesar = findViewById(R.id.btnProcesar);

    //Iniciar servicio de paypal
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, configuration);
    startService(intent);


    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("http://synch.sinergy.solutions:3001/v0/readImg/SACM_MAST_1597884310011.jpeg")
            .into(imgCover);

    btnProcesar.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Lo que esta en clic del boton es la formulación del pago y la inicialización de la activity de paypal.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Creando el pago
    thingsToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(1), "USD", "cover", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent payment = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    payment.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, configuration);
    payment.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingsToBuy);
    startActivityForResult(payment, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Obtiendo el resultado. Dentro del método onActivityResult defino toda la lógica de la respuesta obtenida de la operación PayPal que pueden ser fácilmente validadas a través de códigos que manda PayPal.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        Log.i("Pay", confirmation.toString());

        if(confirmation != null){
            try{
                //informacion extra del pedido
                System.out.println(confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                System.out.println(confirmation.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Orden procesada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El usuario cancelo el pago", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Finalmente el onDestroy

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a el error 404, estas realizando una petición a un recurso que no existe.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-responses/

Además del permiso para conexión a internet, debes declarar el permiso `READ_PHONE_STATE` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Asegurados los permisos anteriores, declara dentro de `<application` de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` el servicio:

```
<service
            android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Si estas usando el modo SANDBOX , es muy importante los datos de esta cuenta.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sandbox-testing/

https://sandbox.paypal.com/

---

Por cierto, para poder cargar la imagen mediante Picasso es importante habilitar la compatibilidad "ClearText" dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

[Mi aplicación Android no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet)