# No descarga archivos desde un webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, descarga, download

No está funcionando la descarga.
Lo tengo en un fragment.
Al presionar sobre el link de la descarga no hace nada. Aunque en algunos celulares arroja como error de descarga.... pero en un A52 no hace nada ni tira error

'''

```
    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        1);
            }

            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    getContext().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Descarga", "No se tiene permiso para descargar archivos.");
            } else {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); //2/ Permitir el escaneo de medios y agregarse a bibliotecas de medios, como álbumes y música, según el tipo de archivos descargados
                request.setMimeType(mimetype);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes( DownloadManager .Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE); //2/ // Permitir descargar el tipo de red
                request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true); //2/// Permitir la descarga en itinerancia
                request.setDescription("Descarga de archivo...");  // Establecer la descripción de la barra de notificaciones
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)); // Establecer el título de la barra de notificaciones, si no se establece, el nombre del archivo se utilizará por defecto
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setAllowedOverMetered(false); // Permitir la descarga con tráfico de facturación
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false); // Permitir que el registro sea visible en la interfaz de administración de descargas
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); // Establece el tipo de visualización de la notificación, muestra la notificación cuando la descarga está en curso y después de la finalización

                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)); // Establece la ruta y el nombre del archivo descargado
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);

            }
        }
    });
```

'''

y en el manifest

Comment: Despues de un rato, en el A52, aparece diciendo "no puede completar la descarga"

Comment: ¿POr qué no lo pones en un `try/catch` e imprimes el error con `log.d` para así saber que está mal desde el `LogCat`?

Comment: uuuuuu porque no se como hacer eso

Comment: Agregue 
 try {
                        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        dm.enqueue(request);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("ORS-Descarga-Error", e.getMessage());
                    }
Pero no me registra nada.... solamente en las notificaciones me indica "No se pudo completar la descarga"

Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ¿En la sección `LogCat - Info` no te figura el error?

Answer (score 1):

Primero asegura que tengas definido en el AndroidManifest el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  y tambièn que este se acepte de otra forma no funcionara.

Dependiendo del tipo de archivo debes definir el [MIME TYPE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) adecuado, revisa la [Lista completa de tipos MIME](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

```
 request.setMimeType(mimetype);
```

Si estas usando `DownloadManager` te sugiero usar un Thread para lograr la descarga.

```
new Thread("Browser download") {
            public void run() {
                dm.enqueue(request);
            }
        }.start();
```

---

Este es un ejemplo completo:

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setMimeType(mimetype);

    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    request.setDescription("Descargando archivo...");
    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
    final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    new Thread("Browser download") {
        public void run() {
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    }.start();
```

---

Actualizaciòn.

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> Les cuento que encontre que si lo bajo desde un http:// NO funciona
> pero si lo hago desde un https:// SI!

el problema principal es que actualmente no se deben usar urls no cifradas en la aplicaciòn, es decir se deben usar urls `https://`, en caso de que estes usando urls `http://` debes habilitar la compatibilidad "ClearText" para que tu aplicaciòn permita conexiones usando `http://`, esto se realiza dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Revisa:

[Mi aplicación android no se conecta a internet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.
1- En el manifest estan
2- mimetype viene como parámetro aca: public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
No lo establezco yo
3- Agregué Thread segun tu codigo de ejemplo pero tampoco funciono

Comment: No estableces tu el mimetype pero imagina que la url sea de un pdf y tu tienes un mime type de archivo de texto o imagen? debes asegurar que la url sea un tipo de archivo definido por el mime type, **Si obtienes un error revisa el Log y ese error debes agregarlo en tu pregunta**", si obtienes error el problema puede ser diverso incluso un detalle particular con el dispositivo

Comment: Les cuento que encontre que si lo bajo desde un https NO funciona pero si lo hago desde un http SIIIIIIII

Comment: @OsirisStto si has definido este dominio en un CA mediante el network security? porque este podria ser tu problema, aun asi te deberia salir este error en el logcat

Comment: esto es super facil desafortunadamente android no lo crea automaticamente en las plantillas a pesar de ser tan indispensable para acceder a recursos https

Comment: Me parece que es al reves, es importante usar urls https:// si no usas este tipo de urls tienes que habilitar desde el AndroidManifest.xml, revisa mi actualizaciòn y trata nuevamente @OsirisStto