# Consulta de grabar los datos de los fragmentos

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, tengo la siguiente inquietud, ya termine los fragment que son cuatro en total sin contar el principal, ahora quiero grabar los datos ingresados en los distintos EditText que se ingresaron con anterioridad:
y este el código que se utiliza en el fragment denominado datos:

```
package com.example.prueba1.Controlador;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.prueba1.R;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class datos extends Fragment {

EditText txtsiniestro,txtregistro1,txtpoliza,txtfechadenuncia,txtfechadesignacion,txtfechainspeccion,
        txtanalista,txtliq,txtitem,txtactivo8,txtregistro,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
Button btn_grabar,btn_buscar,btn_modificar,btn_eliminar,btn_limpiar,btn_salir;
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

public datos() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    txtregistro = view.findViewById(R.id.txtregristro);
    txtsiniestro = view.findViewById(R.id.txtsiniestro);
    txtregistro1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtregistro1);
    txtpoliza = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpoliza);
    txtfechadenuncia = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechadenuncia);
    txtfechadesignacion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechadesignacion);
    txtfechainspeccion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechainspeccion);
    txtanalista = view.findViewById(R.id.txtanalista);
    txtliq = view.findViewById(R.id.txtliq);
    txtitem = view.findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
    txtactivo8 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtactivo8);
    a = view.findViewById(R.id.a);
    b = view.findViewById(R.id.b);
    c = view.findViewById(R.id.c);
    d = view.findViewById(R.id.d);
    e = view.findViewById(R.id.e);
    f = view.findViewById(R.id.f);
    g = view.findViewById(R.id.g);
    h = view.findViewById(R.id.h);
    btn_grabar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_grabar);
    btn_buscar =view.findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar);
    btn_modificar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_modificar);
    btn_eliminar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_eliminar);
    btn_limpiar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_limpiar);
    btn_salir = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_salir);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    txtregistro.setEnabled(false);
    txtliq.setText("N° 2023-*-FVJ/VEH");
    txtsiniestro.requestFocus();

    txtregistro1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.89/oficina/buscar_casos4.php?ID=" + txtregistro1.getText().toString();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            txtsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Siniestro"));
                            txtregistro1.setText(jsonObject.getString("ID"));
                            txtpoliza.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Poliza"));
                            txtfechadenuncia.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
                            txtfechadesignacion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Designacion"));
                            a.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Asegurado"));
                            b.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Asegurado"));
                            c.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Conductor"));
                            d.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Conductor"));
                            e.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Siniestro"));
                            f.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Tercero"));
                            g.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Tercero"));
                            h.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Vehiculo"));
                            txtfechainspeccion.requestFocus();
                            traspaso1();
                            traspaso();
                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Este Registro no ha sido ingresado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtpoliza.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });

    txtfechadenuncia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechadenuncia.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtfechadesignacion.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtfechadesignacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechadesignacion.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtfechainspeccion.requestFocus();
                    traspaso1();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtfechainspeccion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechainspeccion.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtanalista.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    btn_grabar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.89/oficina/insertar_datos.php");
        }
    });

}

private void traspaso(){
    Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("traspaso", a.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("traspaso1", b.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("traspaso2", c.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("traspaso3", d.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("traspaso4", e.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("traspaso5", f.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("traspaso6", g.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("traspaso7", h.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}

private void traspaso1() {
    Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("fecha", txtfechadesignacion.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}

private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {
    asegurado Asegurado = (asegurado) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.asegurado);
    EditText campo1 = Asegurado.txtnombre;
    EditText campo2 = Asegurado.txtrut;
    EditText campo3 = Asegurado.txtdireccion;
    EditText campo4 = Asegurado.txtmail;
    EditText campo5 = Asegurado.txtfono;
    EditText campo6 = Asegurado.txtconductor;
    EditText campo7 = Asegurado.txtrut1;
    EditText campo8 = Asegurado.txtmail1;
    EditText campo9 = Asegurado.txtfono1;
    EditText campo10 = Asegurado.txtlicencia;
    EditText campo11 = Asegurado.txtfechacontrol;
    siniestro Siniestro = (siniestro) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.siniestro);
    EditText campo12 = Siniestro.txtfechasiniestro;
    EditText campo13 = Siniestro.txthora;
    EditText campo14 = Siniestro.txtubicacion;
    EditText campo15 = Siniestro.txtciudad;
    EditText campo16 = Siniestro.txtdescripcion;
    EditText campo17 = Siniestro.txttercero;
    EditText campo18 = Siniestro.txtrut2;
    EditText campo19 = Siniestro.txtfono2;
    EditText campo20 = Siniestro.txtmarcatercero;
    EditText campo21 = Siniestro.txtano;
    EditText campo22 = Siniestro.txtpatentetercero;
    policial Policial = (policial) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.policial);
    EditText campo23 = Policial.et_unidad;
    EditText campo24 = Policial.et_constancia;
    EditText campo25 = Policial.et_parte;
    EditText campo26 = Policial.et_estamento;
    EditText campo27 = Policial.et_causa;
    EditText campo28 = Policial.txtfechaparte;
    EditText campo29 = Policial.txtfechacitacion;
    poliza Poliza = (poliza) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.poliza);
    EditText campo30 = Poliza.txtfechainicio;
    EditText campo31 = Poliza.txtfechatermino;
    EditText campo32 = Poliza.et_descripcion;
    EditText campo33 = Poliza.et_rut;
    EditText campo34 = Poliza.et_corredor;
    EditText campo35 = Poliza.et_cobertura;
    EditText campo36 = Poliza.et_poliza;
    EditText campo37 = Poliza.et_deducible;
    EditText campo38 = Poliza.et_deducible1;
    EditText campo39 = Poliza.et_deducible2;
    EditText campo40 = Poliza.et_monto;
    EditText campo41 = Poliza.txtfechainforme;
    EditText campo42 = Poliza.et_tipo;
    EditText campo43 = Poliza.et_marca;
    EditText campo44 = Poliza.et_modelo;
    EditText campo45 = Poliza.et_motor;
    EditText campo46 = Poliza.et_chasis;
    EditText campo47 = Poliza.et_ano;
    EditText campo48 = Poliza.et_color;
    EditText campo49 = Poliza.et_patente;
    String siniestro,pol,denuncia,designacion,insp,liquidacion,ana,aseg,rut,conductor,rut1,licencia,control,
            fechasin,hora,ubicacion,ciudad,desc,ini,fin,plan,corr,cob,pol1,ded,ded1,tipo,marca,modelo,motor,
            chasis,año,color,patente;
    siniestro = txtsiniestro.getText().toString();
    pol = txtpoliza.getText().toString();
    denuncia = txtfechadenuncia.getText().toString();
    designacion = txtfechadesignacion.getText().toString();
    insp = txtfechainspeccion.getText().toString();
    liquidacion = txtliq.getText().toString();
    ana = txtanalista.getText().toString();
    aseg = campo1.getText().toString();
    rut = campo2.getText().toString();
    conductor = campo6.getText().toString();
    rut1 = campo7.getText().toString();
    licencia = campo10.getText().toString();
    control = campo11.getText().toString();
    fechasin = campo12.getText().toString();
    hora = campo13.getText().toString();
    ubicacion = campo14.getText().toString();
    ciudad = campo15.getText().toString();
    desc = campo16.getText().toString();
    ini = campo30.getText().toString();
    fin = campo31.getText().toString();
    plan = campo32.getText().toString();
    corr = campo34.getText().toString();
    cob = campo35.getText().toString();
    pol1 = campo36.getText().toString();
    ded = campo37.getText().toString();
    ded1 = campo38.getText().toString();
    tipo = campo42.getText().toString();
    marca = campo43.getText().toString();
    modelo = campo44.getText().toString();
    motor = campo45.getText().toString();
    chasis = campo46.getText().toString();
    año = campo47.getText().toString();
    color = campo48.getText().toString();
    patente = campo49.getText().toString();
    if (siniestro.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error, debe ingresar el N° de siniestro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtsiniestro.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (pol.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Póliza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtpoliza.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (denuncia.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error, debe ingresar el campo de la fecha", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtfechadenuncia.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (designacion.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error, debe ingresar el campo de la designación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtfechadesignacion.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (insp.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error, debe ingresar el campo de la inspección", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtfechainspeccion.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (liquidacion.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error, debe ingresar el campo del N° de liquidación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtliq.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (ana.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del analista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtanalista.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (aseg.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Nombre del Asegurado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Asegurado.txtnombre.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (rut.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del RUN o RUT del Asegurado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo2.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (conductor.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo el Nombre del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo6.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (rut1.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo el RUN del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo7.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (licencia.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo la Licencia del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo10.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (control.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Fecha de Control del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo11.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (fechasin.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Fecha del Siniestro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo12.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (hora.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Hora del Siniestro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo13.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (ubicacion.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Ubicación del Siniestro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo14.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (ciudad.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Ciudad del Siniestro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo15.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (desc.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Descripción del Siniestro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo16.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (ini.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del inicio de la póliza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo30.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (fin.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del fin de la póliza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo31.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (plan.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Plan de la póliza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo32.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (corr.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Nombre del Corredor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo34.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (cob.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Cobertura de la Poliza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo35.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (pol1.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del POL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo36.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (ded.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Deducible según contrato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo37.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (ded1.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Valor de la UF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo38.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (tipo.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Tipo del Vehículo Asegurado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo42.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (marca.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Marca del Vehículo Asegurado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo43.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (modelo.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Modelo del Vehículo Asegurado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo44.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (motor.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del N° del Motor del Vehículo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo45.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (chasis.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del N° del Chasis y/o VIN del Vehículo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo46.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (año.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Año del Vehículo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo47.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (color.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del Color del Vehículo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo48.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (patente.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la Patente del Vehículo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        campo49.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, response -> {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Datos grabados satisfactoriamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //limpiardatos();
    }, error -> Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String aa = "1";
            String bb = "0";
            txtactivo8.setText(aa);
            txtitem.setText(bb);
            parametros.put("N_Siniestro",txtsiniestro.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("N_Poliza",txtpoliza.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Item",txtitem.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Fecha_Denuncia",txtfechadenuncia.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Fecha_Designacion",txtfechadesignacion.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Fecha_Inspeccion",txtfechainspeccion.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("N_Liquidacion",txtliq.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Analista",txtanalista.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Nombre_Asegurado",campo1.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Rut_Asegurado",campo2.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Direccion_Asegurado",campo3.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Mail_Asegurado",campo4.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Fono_Asegurado",campo5.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Nombre_Conductor",campo6.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Rut_Conductor",campo7.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Mail_Conductor",campo8.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Fono_Conductor",campo9.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Licencia_Conductor",campo10.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Fecha_Control",campo11.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Activo",txtactivo8.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

el error me dice que Asegurado es null y por ende los edittext estan nulos también, el error se registra en el private ejecutarservicio.

ojala que me puedan asesorar con el error que me envía, ya que es la primera vez que trabajo con los fragmentos, me ha costado llegar a esto de grabar los datos en los distintos fragment, si necesitan otro código que les pueda brindar me informan y desde ya muchas gracias.

De acuerdo a lo solicitado te adjunto el error del logcat:

```
2023-04-28 16:27:05.838 15470-15470/? E/USNET: USNET: appName: com.example.prueba
2023-04-28 16:28:08.342 15470-15470/com.example.prueba E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.prueba, PID: 15470
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.EditText com.example.prueba1.Controlador.asegurado.txtnombre' on a null object reference in method 'void com.example.prueba1.Controlador.datos.ejecutarServicio(java.lang.String)'
    at com.example.prueba1.Controlador.datos.ejecutarServicio(datos.java:233)
    at com.example.prueba1.Controlador.datos.access$500(datos.java:34)
    at com.example.prueba1.Controlador.datos$5.onClick(datos.java:195)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
    at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

y este es el debug del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando realices preguntas te sugiero agregar el error como se muestra en el LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es simplemente que la petición que realizas no obtiene informaciòn.

```
 String url = "http://192.168.1.89/oficina/buscar_casos4.php?ID=" + txtregistro1.getText().toString();
 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
 ...
 ...
```

Debes asegurar que la petición en verdad obtiene información, pero hay algo importante que puede ser la causa del problema, estás usando "`http://`" cuando deberías usar "`https://`", si vas a usar "`http://`" debes configurar en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` que tu aplicación pueda permitir conexiones a urls no cifradas, lo realizas de esta forma:

```
<application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Revisa esta respuesta:

[**Habilitar la compatibilidad "ClearText" usando android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290)

---

Actualización:

El problema es que te encuentras en el `Fragment` `datos`, pero desde aquí tratas de cargar el `Fragment` `asegurado`  y obtener las referencias de sus elementos, esto no es posible,

```
private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {
    asegurado Asegurado = (asegurado) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.asegurado);
    EditText campo1 = Asegurado.txtnombre;
    EditText campo2 = Asegurado.txtrut;
    EditText campo3 = Asegurado.txtdireccion;
    EditText campo4 = Asegurado.txtmail;
    EditText campo5 = Asegurado.txtfono;
    EditText campo6 = Asegurado.txtconductor;
    EditText campo7 = Asegurado.txtrut1;
    EditText campo8 = Asegurado.txtmail1;
    EditText campo9 = Asegurado.txtfono1;
    EditText campo10 = Asegurado.txtlicencia;
    EditText campo11 = Asegurado.txtfechacontrol;
    ...
    ...
```

Debes cambiar a otro `fragment` mediante una transacción y de esta forma podrías obtener sus referencias. **Solo podrás obtener las referencias de las vistas del Fragmento que esté cargado.**

Comment: muy buenos días, te comento que el error que me haces mencion, no es el problemas es en el private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {, el cual se activa una vez que pincho el botón grabar, el que te refieres al string url funcijna muy bien, si lo que quiero es ver el problema es traer los datos del fragment b al frgment a , para poder grabarlo

Comment: de acuerdo al logcat te descroibo las lis leneas del error: por la línea 34 que indica es la siguiente "public class datos extends Fragment {", por la línea "ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.89/oficina/insertar_datos.php");", y por la línea 229 "EditText campo1 = Asegurado.txtnombre;", eso es porque el fragment asegurado trae null, según la imagen que se muestra, por lo de la línea 198, siempre lo hago asi con los activity y nunca me dan problema, ahora con los fragment puede ser el error, ojala que me puedas asesorar, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Pero agrega que mensaje de error es especificamente, busca donde diga "Caused by"

Comment: de acuerdo a lo solicitado es lo que me envía el error en el logcat

Comment: Ya vi cual es el problema, agregue una actualización, no puedes cargar otro fragment a menos que realices una transacción y solo podrás obtener las referencias de sus vistas si el Fragment esta cargado.

Comment: es exacto el problema es que no me carga el fragment llamado asegurado y se traspasa a la varariable Asegurado para así poder llamar a los datos ingresados y poder grabarlos, lo realice así como lo menciona, si al final encontré la solución con mucho más líneas de código, pero me funciona

Answer (score 0):

amigos del foro he encontrado una solución a mi dilema, no es la optima ya que posee mucho más líneas de códigos, pero es lo que hay, ojala que les sirva de ayuda para todos:

```
private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("traspaso", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
            String valor = bundle.getString("campo1");
            String valor1 = bundle.getString("campo2");
            String valor2 = bundle.getString("campo3");
            String valor3 = bundle.getString("campo4");
            String valor4 = bundle.getString("campo5");
            String valor5 = bundle.getString("campo6");
            String valor6 = bundle.getString("campo7");
            String valor7 = bundle.getString("campo8");
            String valor8 = bundle.getString("campo9");
            String valor9 = bundle.getString("campo10");
            String valor10 = bundle.getString("campo11");
            a.setText(valor);
            b.setText(valor1);
            c.setText(valor2);
            d.setText(valor3);
            e.setText(valor4);
            f.setText(valor5);
            g.setText(valor6);
            h.setText(valor7);
            i.setText(valor8);
            j.setText(valor9);
            k.setText(valor10);
        }
    });
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("traspaso1", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
            String valor11 = bundle.getString("campo12");
            String valor12 = bundle.getString("campo13");
            String valor13 = bundle.getString("campo14");
            String valor14 = bundle.getString("campo15");
            String valor15 = bundle.getString("campo16");
            String valor16 = bundle.getString("campo17");
            String valor17 = bundle.getString("campo18");
            String valor18 = bundle.getString("campo19");
            String valor19 = bundle.getString("campo20");
            String valor20 = bundle.getString("campo21");
            String valor21 = bundle.getString("campo22");
            l.setText(valor11);
            m.setText(valor12);
            n.setText(valor13);
            o.setText(valor14);
            p.setText(valor15);
            q.setText(valor16);
            r.setText(valor17);
            s.setText(valor18);
            t.setText(valor19);
            u.setText(valor20);
            v.setText(valor21);
        }
    });
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("traspaso2", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
            String valor22 = bundle.getString("campo23");
            String valor23 = bundle.getString("campo24");
            String valor24 = bundle.getString("campo25");
            String valor25 = bundle.getString("campo26");
            String valor26 = bundle.getString("campo27");
            String valor27 = bundle.getString("campo28");
            String valor28 = bundle.getString("campo29");
            w.setText(valor22);
            x.setText(valor23);
            y.setText(valor24);
            z.setText(valor25);
            aa.setText(valor26);
            ab.setText(valor27);
            ac.setText(valor28);
        }
    });
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("traspaso3", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
            String valor29 = bundle.getString("campo30");
            String valor30 = bundle.getString("campo31");
            String valor31 = bundle.getString("campo32");
            String valor32 = bundle.getString("campo33");
            String valor33 = bundle.getString("campo34");
            String valor34 = bundle.getString("campo35");
            String valor35 = bundle.getString("campo36");
            String valor36 = bundle.getString("campo37");
            String valor37 = bundle.getString("campo38");
            String valor38 = bundle.getString("campo39");
            String valor39 = bundle.getString("campo40");
            String valor40 = bundle.getString("campo41");
            String valor41 = bundle.getString("campo42");
            String valor42 = bundle.getString("campo43");
            String valor43 = bundle.getString("campo44");
            String valor44 = bundle.getString("campo45");
            String valor45 = bundle.getString("campo46");
            String valor46 = bundle.getString("campo47");
            String valor47 = bundle.getString("campo48");
            String valor48 = bundle.getString("campo49");
            ad.setText(valor29);
            ae.setText(valor30);
            af.setText(valor31);
            ag.setText(valor32);
            ah.setText(valor33);
            ai.setText(valor34);
            aj.setText(valor35);
            ak.setText(valor36);
            al.setText(valor37);
            am.setText(valor38);
            an.setText(valor39);
            ap.setText(valor40);
            aq.setText(valor41);
            ar.setText(valor42);
            as.setText(valor43);
            at.setText(valor44);
            au.setText(valor45);
            av.setText(valor46);
            aw.setText(valor47);
            ax.setText(valor48);
        }
    });
```