# Error al intentar acceder a API DataSnap desde dispositivo Android sobre protocolo HTTP

Tags: android, http, delphi, datasnap

Hace 2 días adquirí los servicios de un *hosting* para compartir mi base de datos Firebird 4.0; ademas instalé mi servidor *datasnap* hecho en Delphi.

Los clientes Windows trabajan bien, me muestra los datos; sin embargo en el cliente Android, no. Cuando pido una consulta sale el siguiente error:

```
java.io.IOexception: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 190.XXX.XX.XXX not permitted
```

Gracias la ayuda que puedan prestarme.

Comment: ¿Qué API Level tiene tu aplicación?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para iniciarte en el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Creaste otra cuenta? no tienes acceso a la original? detectamos que tenes dos cuentas.. necesitas unirlas?

Answer (score 0):

La recomendación principal es que te comuniques con tu servidor utilizando el protocolo HTTPS y no HTTP.

Ha habido mucho debate en Android sobre esto, pero lo cierto es que desde [Android Marshmallow (API 23)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Marshmallow), que es de septiembre de 2015 la configuración por defecto cambió para no permitir las comunicaciones en texto claro vía HTTP.

Recuerda que los dispositivos móviles, por naturaleza, se conectan a redes hostiles y el tráfico en texto plano, de entrada, sería visible para quienes estén en dichas redes, y esto podría terminar haciendo tu aplicación más vulnerable.<sup>1</sup>

Si después de dicho esto, aún quieres comunicarte vía HTTP, puedes seguir los siguientes pasos:

- Prepara un archivo [`network_security_config.xml`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config), según las especificaciones.  El archivo debiera lucir más o menos como el ejemplo siguiente:

  ```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">midominio.com</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
  ```

  Otro ejemplo de archivo es este:

  ```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="system" />
            </trust-anchors>
        </base-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
           <domain includeSubdomains="true">midominio.com</domain>
           <domain includeSubdomains="true">190.14.17.54</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
  ```

  Asegúrate de incluir el atributo `cleartextTrafficPermitted` y trata de limitar los subdominios, si es posible. Es mejor permitir directamente, por ejemplo, a `api.midominio.com` o `miapp.midominino.com` que permitir todos los subdominios de `midominio.com`. En el caso de IP's, solo puedes poner IP's específicas y, hasta donde entiendo, no rangos  de IP's.
- Agrega el archivo a la lista de archivos que se incluyen en la distribución de la aplicación en Android (Deploy), asegurándote que la ruta remota sea `res\xml\`, según se muestra en la imagen.

  [image: Archivos a distribuir en Android]
- Modifica el archivo `AndroidManifest.template.xml` de tu proyecto, agregando al nodo `<application>` la línea:

  ```xml
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  ```

A estas alturas, puedes compilar y desplegar el proyecto en el dispositivo Android.

Puedes hacer el [Codelab de configuración de seguridad de red de Android](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config?hl=es-419#0) para familiarizarte más con estos conceptos, aunque está diseñado para hacerlo en Android Studio, la plataforma de destino es la misma.

Documentación y referencias:

- [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)
- [Delphi HTTP Clear Text Traffic on FMX Android](https://synaptica.info/en/2022/04/20/delphi-http-clear-text-traffic-on-fmx-android/)
- [Respuesta a Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/255257) en StackOverflow (en inglés).

**Aviso**: Escribo esta respuesta con el afán de ayudar, no doy garantía sobre el código o las instrucciones en sus versiones iniciales, pues en lo personal solo uso comunicación vía HTTPS. Si hay algún error, por favor deja un comentario y así espero lleguemos a un procedimiento bien descrito y aplicable.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Sobra decir que yo apoyo el razonamiento que llevó a cambiar esta configuración default.

Answer (score 0):

El error :

> java.io.IOexception: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 190.XXX.XX.XXX not
> permitted

indica que tu aplicación Android no permitirá acceder a las URL que usen **HTTP** de forma predeterminada, de forma predeterminada solo se permite usar **HTTPS**.

Por cuestiones de seguridad esto se desabilito desde Android 9  (nivel de API 28), así que si tu app está creada para este sistema operativo o uno superior (ver compileSdkVersion) la compatibilidad con texto sin cifrar está deshabilitada de forma predeterminada y se requerirá la configuración de texto sin cifrar de HTTP para acceder a los sitios **HTTP**.

**Para esto debes habilitar la compatibilidad "ClearText" para que te permita conexiones usando `http://`**, esto se realiza dentro de tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Revisa:

**["Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet/320290#320290)**

**Sin duda, la solución óptima es que tus conexiones sean cifradas usando `https://` y no `http://`**