# webview_flutter - Failed to validate the certificate chain

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart, programación-móvil

Al querer ingresar a una web con webview_flutter me sale el siguiente error:

**I/cr_X509Util( 5490): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/chromium( 5490): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202**

Cabe mencionar que solo me pasa con Android, en iOS no tengo ese problema,

**Versión:
webview_flutter: ^4.7.0**

Comment: Agrega la parte donde tratas de cargar la url en tu WebView por favor.

Answer (score 0):

El mismo error indica el problema:

> Failed to validate the certificate chain, error:
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found. E/chromium( 5490):
> [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1,
> SSL error code 1, net_error -202

refiere a que no se pudo validar el certificado SSL de tu página, comentas que es únicamente en iOS, puede ser que en Android se tenga [desabilitado el soporte ClearText en tu AndroidManifest.xml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320269/mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-9-no-se-conecta-a-internet-cleartext-http-traffic-not-pe), pero en el caso de ambas plataformas lo ideal es usar una url cifrada con certificado SSL.

---

Si usas un certificado en tu app (`.pem`), carga desde assets el certificado de esta forma, asgurando definir la url de tu página web

```
WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://url de tu página web',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) async {        
          ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/ssl_certificate.pem'); //* Carga certificado.
          String certificate = String.fromCharCodes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
          await webViewController.loadUrl(
            'url de tu página web',
            headers: {'certificate': certificate},
          );
        },
      ),
```